# Python Pandas XLRDError when reading .xls files

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a problem with reading `.xls` files in Pandas.

Here's the code

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xls')
```

And the output states,

```
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xff\xfeD\x00A\x00T\x00'
```

Anyone experiencing the same issue? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

```py
# Changing the data types of all strings in the module at once
from __future__ import unicode_literals
# Used to save the file as excel workbook
# Need to install this library
from xlwt import Workbook
# Used to open to corrupt excel file
import io

filename = r'sample.xls'
# Opening the file using 'utf-16' encoding
file1 = io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-16")
data = file1.readlines()

# Creating a workbook object
xldoc = Workbook()
# Adding a sheet to the workbook object
sheet = xldoc.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
# Iterating and saving the data to sheet
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    # Two things are done here
    # Removeing the '\n' which comes while reading the file using io.open
    # Getting the values after splitting using '\t'
    for j, val in enumerate(row.replace('\n', '').split('\t')):
        sheet.write(i, j, val)

# Saving the file as an excel file
xldoc.save('1.xls')
```

Credits to this [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@jerilkuriakose/recover-corrupt-excel-file-xls-or-xlsx-using-python-2eea6bb07aae)